# inserting images to table view don't cover the whole screen

Tags: java, android, tableview, image-resizing, screen-resolution

[image]
When my images are in a resolution of 128x128 and inserted to a tableview(that should cover the whole screen), they don't cover the whole screen but when I resize them to 256x256 then they cover the whole screen. Can't I use 9 patch image or something else to make them cover the whole screen and behave as needed in any screen resolution? Must I use the density?

I tried to set fitXY to my views but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm not sure if needed but here's my code:

I created 4 gif image buttons and added them to a list of gif image buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    GifImageButton myButton = new GifImageButton();
    myButton.setBackgroundResource(drawables[i]); // add some drawable to the button background
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
    listButtons.add(myButton);
}
```

Then I created a tablelayout (rows = 2, columns = 2) programmatically and added it to my layout:

```
MyTableLayout tableLayout = new MyTableLayout(this);
tableLayout.createTableLayoutOfButtons(tableRows /*=2*/, tableCols /*=2*/, listButtons);
mylinearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

my MyTableLayout class is:

```
public class MyTableLayout extends TableLayout {

    public MyTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // indexListButtons is the current index of the listButtons elements. so as long as there are buttons, we will add them to the table rows
    int indexListButtons = 0;
    public void createTableLayoutOfButtons(int numRows, int numCols, List<GifImageButton> listButtons) {
        setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
            tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j, ++indexListButtons) {
                // indices 0, 1, 2, 3
                if (indexListButtons < listButtons.size()) {
                    tableRow.addView(listButtons.get(indexListButtons));
                }
                // indices bigger than 3 don't exist so insert empty views in order to make each of the views in the same size
                else {
                    // not enough buttons
                    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
                Button btn = new Button(getContext());
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tableRow.addView(btn);
                }
            }
            addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

**======**

**EDIT**

**======**

Veselin Todorov, let me understand if this was your meaning. thanks..

```
public class MyTableLayout extends TableLayout {

    public MyTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // indexListButtons is the current index of the listButtons elements. so     as long as there are buttons, we will add them to the table rows
    int indexListButtons = 0;
    public void createTableLayoutOfButtons(int numRows, int numCols,     List<GifImageButton> listButtons) {
        setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
            LinearLayout newLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            newLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
            newLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            tableRow.addView(newLinearLayout, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
            tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j, ++indexListButtons) {
                // indices 0, 1, 2, 3
                if (indexListButtons < listButtons.size()) {
                    newLinearLayout.addView(listButtons.get(indexListButtons));
                }
                // indices bigger than 3 don't exist so insert empty views     in order to make each of the views in the same size
                else {
                    // not enough buttons
                    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new     TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
                    Button btn = new Button(getContext());
                    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                    btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    newLinearLayout.addView(btn);
                }
            }
            addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can achieve this by setting weight for your table row's height the same way you're doing it for the buttons width. This way the table rows shoul split the remaining free space between themselves and you'll get rows of equal height that fill all the vertical space.

Comment: tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    0, 1.0f));

did you mean like this? it changes nothing :\

Comment: Yeah you're right the TableLayout documentation says that if the child is a TableRow the height is always WRAP_CONTENT so weight will not help. I see two ways to fix this: 
- You can either calculate view sizes yourself. Do this in a post runnable so the size is set on the next frame where your parent layout has measured its height already. Then you can just set your buttons height to half of the parent height and the table rows will be resized correctly.
- The other way is to just use a vertical LinearLayout with two child LinearLayouts with their weights set.

Comment: Thanks for you effort! so about the second way, do you mean that every row will contain a linearLayout that will contain the 2 views? I tried it now but I can't see the views\table. I'll edit the question with this change so please take a look if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the expected result by doing something like this:

```
    LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(context);
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // for(etc. etc.)
    LinearLayout currentRow = new LinearLayout(context);
    currentRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, 0);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    currentRow.setLayoutParams(params);

    View viewOne = new View(context);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
    viewOne.setLayoutParams(params);
    currentRow.addView(viewOne);

    View viewTwo = new View(context);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
    viewTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
    currentRow.addView(viewTwo);

    main.addView(currentRow);
    //} end of for
```

You can wrap the code that creates the "currentRow" layout in your loop if you need more rows. This way you don't have to use a table layout and its relatively simple to create. The downside is it's not that efficient because it uses nested layouts but should not be a problem.

Another thing to consider is if you need many rows like 10 or more you should probably use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager so you don't create too much views and a very heavy layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I tried to fix it so many hours! :) I appreciate your help! it worked well! and just an edit: the params for the views should get 1.0f as the third parameter: params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
because without it, each row contains 1 element.
again thanks!

Comment: @ErezShmiel Yeah you're right I forgot to add weight to the views themselves. Glad it solved your problem :)